# Disable Button until all textfields have been Filled Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield

I have looked everywhere for this answer but I haven't gotten a simple easy to follow answer to this question. I have 8 text fields that I need to fill out before I click and submit before moving onto the next page. I have hooked up each of the textfields to view controller.h file but I don't know how to disable the submit button easily step by step. Thank you so much for the help in advance.

I have tried this from a previous post but I could not get it to work..

Make an Outlet for every UITextField and create an IBAction in your .h:

```
IBOutlet UITextField *textField1;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField2;
IBOutlet UITextField *textField3;
IBOutlet UIButton *button

- (IBAction)editingChanged;
```

Connect all the outlets and connect the IBAction to every textfield with editingChanged:

```
 - (IBAction)editingChanged {
    if ([textfield1.text length] != 0 && [textfield2.text length] != 0 && [textfield3.text length] != 0) {
         [button setEnabled:YES];
     }
     else {
         [button setEnabled:NO];
     }
 }
```

Note that you can also use `[textfield.text isEqualToString:@""]` and put a ! in front of it (!means 'not' in objective-c) to recognize the empty textField, and say 'if the textField is empty do...'

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [button setEnabled:NO];
}
```

Comment: Why didn't this work? What happened?

Comment: I just got lost in the direction. so what does it mean to connect all outlets and connect the inaction ro every textfield with editingChanged?

Comment: Which event are you connecting to editingChanged?

Comment: Thats the part where I am getting confused about. Those directions were in a different post and I tried to follow but I was lost. so 1st. make the IBAction in the interface part of the view controller.h file and then after that I'm lost..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this,

1) You need to add textfiled delegate function to all your textfiled.

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set submit button disable
    submitbtn.enable=NO

   textfiled1.delegate = self;
   textfiled2.delegate = self;
   textfiled3.delegate = self;
   textfiled4.delegate = self;
   textfiled5.delegate = self;
   textfiled6.delegate = self;
   textfiled7.delegate = self;
   textfiled8.delegate = self;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
  //check your all texfield length if not equal to zero in below if(condition)
   if(alltextfiled_length != 0)
   {
     submitbtn.enable=YES
   }
   else
   {
     submitbtn.enable=NO
   } 
}
```

Comment: Would the submitbtn be an ib action in the .h area correct? Or would I also have to make an outlet in the .h file as well?

Comment: @Neil, Make an Outlet in the .h file.

Comment: The problem that I am facing is that it does not allow me to reference the textfield_length properly. Like my UITextField is called "Card_number" it does not allow me to put "Card_number_length"..

Comment: @Neil, I didn't mean alltextfiled_length is a obj-c code, I just say logic, K fine replace (alltextfiled_length) as (yourtextfield.text.length !=0)

Comment: @Neil, Check first textFieldDidEndEditing function whether working or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83346/discussion-between-neil-and-manikandan-d).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html) on connecting outlets.

To handle changes in the text fields your view controller class could conform to the [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) protocol, assign your view controller as the delegate of each text field, and implement `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField` which will be called when tapping the Return button on each text field's keyboard.